# YouTube Data API v3 quota for query per day set to 0

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are using YouTube Data API v3 for quite some time now but suddenly it started responding with error 403 saying that the access needs to be enabled.

Here is the error message:

```
{
  "code": 403,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "usageLimits",
      "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project {projectId} before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project={projectId} then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
      "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
      "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project={projectId}"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project {projectId} before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project={projectId} then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
}
```

We have disable and re-enable all api wee use (youtube-data-api-v3, contacts api, google+ api). We have also try to generate new client-id and client secret without success.

Finally we have noticed that quota for request per day have been set to 0.
This is certainly the raison of why request we can not make any request to API, but we can not change this value.

Anyone have faced this issue before ?
What can i do to raise the limit of the quota ?

Comment: Have you found solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

See this issue [#211012781](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/211012781)

> Hi. If you're seeing Queries per day quota set to 0 and the API is indeed enabled, then this means that your project’s access to YouTube Data API Service has been disabled.

> You should’ve received a notice via email regarding this action, which also contains the steps that need to be taken to regain the project’s access. But just in case you missed it, please fill out and submit the exceptions form below:

https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form?hl=en

Answer (score -2):

It is stated somewhere that you should link to a billing account and then you can raise the limit from zero to anything.

Comment: Hi DoubleB, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Somewhere where? Can you please put the source of your info, and quote the important parts? See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).